# What is the fastest way to split bayer data 1D array to 4 1D color arrays, and how to combine them back?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm totally new to python, so I'm not familiar with the array slicing magic. What is the **fastest** way to do two following tasks?

**Task 1**

I have 1D numpy array containing data organized in following manner (it is a stream of Bayer data coming from image sensor):

```
[0, 1, 0, 1 ... 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3 ... 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1 ... 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
                            ^                          ^                          ^
```

where numbers are indicators what output array this cell should go to, and ^ are equal intervals. In other words: first N cells should go to the arrays 0 and 1, then N cells to arrays 2 and 3, repeat till the end.

Now I have following code that works as intended, but I'm sure is far from being optimal speed wise:

```
def splitVectorToColorPlanes(cfa, imageHeight, imageWidth) -> ndarray:
    cfaMatrix = np.reshape(cfa, (imageHeight, imageWidth))

    colorPlanes = np.empty((4, cfa.size // 4), dtype = np.uint16)

    for i in range(0, imageHeight, 2):
        splitRow = np.reshape(cfaMatrix[i], (2, imageWidth // 2), order = "F")

        colorPlanes[2 * i % 2][i // 2 * imageWidth // 2:(i // 2 + 1) * imageWidth // 2] = splitRow[0]
        colorPlanes[2 * i % 2 + 1][i // 2 * imageWidth // 2:(i // 2 + 1) * imageWidth // 2] = splitRow[1]

        splitRow = np.reshape(cfaMatrix[i + 1], (2, imageWidth // 2), order = "F")

        colorPlanes[2 * i % 2 + 2][i // 2 * imageWidth // 2:(i // 2 + 1) * imageWidth // 2] = splitRow[0]
        colorPlanes[2 * i % 2 + 3][i // 2 * imageWidth // 2:(i // 2 + 1) * imageWidth // 2] = splitRow[1]

    return colorPlanes
```

**Task 2**

Reverse task 1 - I have 4 arrays, and I need to combine it to 1.

So for the task 1 I need to

1. split one array to two with the rule: first N elements of the source array go to the 1st intermediate array, then N elements of the source array go to the 2nd intermediate array, repeat.
2. split 1st intermediate array to two out arrays with the rule: every 1st element goes to the 1st out array, every 2nd element goes to the 2nd out array, repeat. Split 2nd intermediate array to 3 and 4 out arrays in the same way.

I hope that description is clear.

Maybe there is a lib doing this so I do not need to reinvent the wheel?

P.S. Please note, I do not need to debayer data, I only need to split it to arrays by colors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably this code is not the fastest possible, but it is fast *enough* for my needs.

```
def splitBayerToChannels(bayer: ndarray[np.uint16]) -> ndarray[np.uint16]:
    r1 = bayer[::2].reshape((-1))
    r2 = bayer[1::2].reshape((-1))

    channels = np.empty((4, bayer.size // 4), dtype = np.uint16)
    channels[0] = r1[::2]
    channels[1] = r1[1::2]
    channels[2] = r2[::2]
    channels[3] = r2[1::2]
    return channels


def assembleChannelsToBayer(channels: ndarray[np.uint16], imageHeight: int, imageWidth: int) -> ndarray[np.uint16]:
    r1 = np.reshape(np.reshape(np.row_stack((channels[0], channels[1])), (1, channels[0].size * 2), "F"), (imageHeight // 2, imageWidth))
    r2 = np.reshape(np.reshape(np.row_stack((channels[2], channels[3])), (1, channels[0].size * 2), "F"), (imageHeight // 2, imageWidth))
    return np.hstack((r1, r2))
```

For 80 megapixel image it takes 100 ms to split bayer to channels, and 260 ms to assemble channels to bayer on the laptop with i7-10510U.

Comment: No, it appears to be incorrect: splitBayerToChannels gives different result than splitVectorToColorPlanes on simple test array

Comment: splitBayerToChannels is just a replacement of splitVectorToColorPlanes, and splitBayerToChannels is correctly working one. It works in real project so I'm confident with it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea from Paul Jurczak at
https://forum.image.sc/t/processing-raw-bayer-data-with-scikit-image/72707 :

```
r = rggb[::2, ::2]
g1 = rggb[::2, 1::2]
g2 = rggb[1::2, ::2]
b = rggb[1::2, 1::2]
```

I rewrote splitBayerToChannels and assembleChannelsToBayer as this:

```
def splitBayerToChannels(bayer, imageHeight, imageWidth):
    if imageWidth % 2 != 0 or imageHeight % 2 != 0:
        print("Only support even width and height")
        return None
    print("splitBayerToChannels")
    print(bayer)
    bayer = np.reshape(bayer, (imageHeight,-1))
    print(bayer)
    r = bayer[::2, ::2]
    g1 = bayer[::2, 1::2]
    g2 = bayer[1::2, ::2]
    b = bayer[1::2, 1::2]
    print(r)
    print(g1)
    print(g2)
    print(b)
    rr = r.reshape((-1))
    rg1 = g1.reshape((-1))
    rg2 = g2.reshape((-1))
    rb = b.reshape((-1))
    print(rr)
    print(rg1)
    print(rg2)
    print(rb)
    channels = np.empty((4, bayer.size // 4), dtype = np.uint16)
    channels[0] = rr
    channels[1] = rg1
    channels[2] = rg2
    channels[3] = rb
    print("channels:")
    print(channels)
    return channels

def assembleChannelsToBayer(channels, imageHeight, imageWidth):
    if imageWidth % 2 != 0 or imageHeight % 2 != 0:
        print("Only support even width and height")
        return None
    print("assembleChannelsToBayer")
    print(channels)
    rr = channels[0]
    rg1 = channels[1]
    rg2 = channels[2]
    rb = channels[3]
    r = rr.reshape((int(imageHeight/2), -1))
    g1 = rg1.reshape((int(imageHeight/2), -1))
    g2 = rg2.reshape((int(imageHeight/2), -1))
    b = rb.reshape((int(imageHeight/2), -1))
    print(r)
    print(g1)
    print(g2)
    print(b)
    bayer = np.empty((imageHeight, imageWidth), r.dtype)
    bayer[::2,::2] = r[::1,::1]
    bayer[::2,1::2] = g1[::1,::1]
    bayer[1::2,::2] = g2[::1,::1]
    bayer[1::2,1::2] = b[::1,::1]
    bayer = bayer.reshape((-1))
    print("bayer:")
    print(bayer)
    return bayer
```

Now splitBayerToChannels returns the same result as splitVectorToColorPlanes. For example, on sample array:

```
bayer =  np.array([  
           0,  10,  1,  11,   2,  12, 
         100, 110,101, 111, 102, 112,
           3,  13,  4,  14,   5,  15,
         103, 113,104, 114, 105, 115])
```

it returns

```
[[  0   1   2   3   4   5]
 [ 10  11  12  13  14  15]
 [100 101 102 103 104 105]
 [110 111 112 113 114 115]]
```